# F# Array2D slices

Tags: f#

is it possible to slice Array2D in F#?
say, 
`let tmp =Array2D.init 100 100 (fun x y -> x * 100 + y)`

how to retrieve some columns or some rows from `tmp` like `tmp.[0,1..]`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  It's easy to grab 2D chunks:

```
tmp.[10..20,30..40]
```

However, if you want a 1D slice, I believe you'll need to project it out of a 2D slice

```
tmp.[0..0,1..] |> fun arr -> Array.init 99 (fun i -> arr.[0,i])
```

Answer (score 9):

When extracting 1D sections from 2D arrays, I find it handy to use `Seq.Cast<T>`. It yields elements from a 2D array in left-right/top-bottom order.

Like this:

```
let A = array2D [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]]

let flatten (A:'a[,]) = A |> Seq.cast<'a>

let getColumn c (A:_[,]) =
    flatten A.[*,c..c] |> Seq.toArray

let getRow r (A:_[,]) =
    flatten A.[r..r,*] |> Seq.toArray
```

And an example in FSI:

```
> flatten A;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2; 3; 4; ...]
> getRow 2 A;;
val it : int array = [|7; 8; 9|]
> getColumn 0 A;;
val it : int array = [|1; 4; 7|]
```

Comment: Great, then I also get fold and all that stuff.

Answer (score 7):

In F# 3.1 you can do this:

```
// Get row 3 from a matrix as a vector:
matrix.[3, *]

// Get column 3 from a matrix as a vector:
matrix.[*, 3]
```

(see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Is there an effective way to get the diagonals aswell?

Answer (score 5):

You have provided an answer yourself.

The sample code in your question will give you exactly what you want.
I have changed it only slightly to better show that it works.

```
let tmp = Array2D.init 10 10 (fun x y -> sprintf "%d,%d" x y)
//3rd row
let row3 = tmp.[2,0..]
//2nd column
let col2 = tmp.[0..,1]
;;
```

The key thing here is to use a single value for a row or column. It then gives you a slice as a 1D array. If you use ranges for both rows and columns then you get a slice of type Array2D.

Edit: Works on Visual F# 3.1.1, older versions not tested.

Comment: maybe you should add that this is a newer F# feature - the question is a bit older - but still a valuable update - thanks for going over this old stuff again!

Comment: Thx, I would if I have known it was. I use Visual F# 3.1.1 and it works - don't know about older versions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, try this `tmp.[0..0, 1..]`

```
let tmp = Array2D.init 100 100 (fun x y -> x * 100 + y)
printf "%A" tmp.[1..2, ..3]

[[100; 101; 102; 103]
 [200; 201; 202; 203]]
```

If you only want one row or column you have to repeat the number.

```
[1..1, 2..3]
[1..2, 2..2]
```

If you want up to or after just leave the number out.

```
[1.., 2..3]
[..2, 2..2]
```

Array slicing always returns the same order array.

```
> tmp.[1..1, 2..2]
val it : int [,] = [[102]]

> tmp.[1..1, 2..2].[0, 0]
val it : int = 102
```